# Using model in views / controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use codeigniter for web development. As I am learning it more, I am finding some more issues that I cannot get a proper logical implementation.

I have a `article_controller.php` and a view `article.php` . I am trying to display all of the article titles on the page. (This code is just for testing purpose).

Lets say I have another table named `images` which contains all the images used in the article. So can I use the `images_m.php` model on the `article.php` view.

**Article_Controller.php**

```
$data['articles'] = $this->article_m->get(); //gets all of the articles 
$this->load->view('articles',$data);
```

**Article.php**

```
foreach($articles as $article):
    echo $article->title;
    $images = $this->images_m->get_by(array('article_id'=>$article->id)); //gets all the images for current article

    foreach(images as $image):
        echo "<img src='./uploads/".$image->filename ."'/>";
    endforeach; 

endforeach;
```

The code works perfectly fine. I have used similar code in a number of websites.
But the main issue is, I have read that it is not a good idea to use `models` in views. Use `models` in `controllers` instead.

So how can I fetch the images for a particular article in a controller.

Comment: I'd prefer doing this via SQL rather than PHP.

Comment: can you tell me is Article data and Article image both are stored in same table?

Comment: @RameezSOOMRO Sorry for the late response. No they are on different table. Thats the main purpose to access them from different tables. If they were in the same table there wouldnt be any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get images in your controller and merge the images object with each article object and pass it to view

```
$articles= $this->article_m->get(); //gets all of the articles 

foreach($articles as $article):

    $article->article_images = $this->images_m->get_by(array('article_id'=>$article->id)); //gets all the images for current article   
endforeach;

$data['articles']=$articles;
$this->load->view('articles',$data);
```

MAke sure you have loaded the `images_m` model in controller

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (pseudo-code) might work:

Controller:

```
$articles = $this->article_m->get();
$images = array();

foreach($articles as $article):
    $images[$article->id] = array();

    $article_images = $this->images_m->get_by(array('article_id'=>$article->id));
    foreach($article_images as $image):
        $images[$article->id][] = './uploads/'.$image->filename;
    endforeach; 
endforeach;

$data['articles'] = $articles;
$data['images'] = $images;

$this->load->view('articles',$data);
```

View:

```
foreach($articles as $article):
    echo $article->title;

    foreach($images[$article->id] as $image):
        echo "<img src='$image'/>";
    endforeach; 

endforeach;
```

Basically just do the same work you were doing in the view and do it in the controller instead. Then throw it in the `$data` array and send it to the view.

---

Edit: I'd recommend looking at @dianuj's answer :)